# How can i import excel sheet in python and represent the columns of sheet using dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy

Import pandas as pd
Data=pd.read_excel("file.xlsx",sheetname="sheet1")

Answer (score 1):

Use ExcelFile.

```
df = pd.ExcelFile(filename.xlsx)

for sh in df.sheet_names:
    if sh == "desiredSheetName":
        dfn = df.parse(sh)
```

You can now use dfn and process the sheet.